# django - post form on select

Tags: django, forms, post, submit, html-select

I made a simple django form, with a list of choices (in radio buttons):

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
            choices=forms.ChoiceField( widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=[(k,k) for k in ['one','two','three']],label="choose one")
```

I would like the form to submit automatically when a user selects one of the options. In straightforward HTML I would've done it as

```
  <select name='myselect' onChange="FORM_NAME.submit();">
    ....
  </select>
```

But I do not know how to integrate this into the form class without writing a template. Specifically, I would need to know `FORM_NAME` so I can call `FORM_NAME.submit()` in the above snippet. 
Can it be done without using a template?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you do not need to know the form name. This should work as well:

```
<select name='myselect' onChange="this.form.submit();">
```

A quick solution to integrate this into your form would involve adding a [attribute to your widget](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances).

```
widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'})
```

Now one could argue if this isn't better separated from your form definition (separating definition, style and behaviour), but that should do it.

Comment: Inline event handling as an element attribute? That's a blast from the past! If you can include jQuery and get to grips with it I'd go for that approach, which allows you to easily drop the onChange attribute entirely, in favour of binding the form submit action to the select element change event via the jQuery "document ready" event. This is better shown as: `$(function() { $('#id_myselect').change(function() { this.form.submit(); }) });`

Comment: Then you could remove the "onChange" attribute from the HTML <select> element and avoid any need for a custom Django form field widget declaration. The <select> tag (with ID) would look like: <select name="myselect" id="id_myselect"> and you could put the Javascript in a separate file, further keeping the markup "clean".