# Can I add a 'shortcut' link to a Django form which edits a field and saves everything?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-crispy-forms

I have a Django (crispy) form with many tabs which all contain many fields. Each of these tabs has an Active boolean field. The first tab of my the form contains an overview, listing all the tabs.

Now I would like to know if there is some way to have a link on that overview tab which would in theory toggle the corresponding boolean field on one of the tabs and save the result. Right now the user can go to the specific tab, check or uncheck the value and save it, but they want some sort of shortcut so they can do it in one click.

Would that be possible at all? And how could I achieve this ?

[image: Overview Tab]

So clicking the Activate / Deactivate in this list should be the same as :

[image: Detail Tab]

Going to the corresponding tab and checking / unchecking the available field and pressing the save button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript and do onchange for checkbox. In the script you can call the views to save the value to database and return to same page.

Comment: Any example code I could try, I'm really new to all that Django and JavaScript stuff.

Comment: If you are having checkbox or radiobutton, in the form you can add attrs as "onchange": form.submit. Refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934839/django-post-form-on-select

Then you can process the form to save the data.

Comment: I do not want the form to submit / save when the user manually checks the checkbox. I only want the value to change and save itself when the user clicks one of those links though ...

Comment: Okay.. in that case, on clicking the checkbox, you make the window to load certain url.. in the urls.py, get that url and in respective views.py, make changes to the value then return to same page.

Comment: Well, it seems I've been able to do it with some Javascript, is there some way I could make it refresh the same page after the submit? Normally it's set up to return to the list view, but in this specific case I would love if it just submits and refreshes the same page.

Comment: In the view, you can use return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')) which will load the same page.